# Is it possible to unit test that my package does not import a specific package?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I want to make sure my Go package use var instances provided by a "dal" package and does not accidentally import and use db access packages directly.

I guess I can do regexp search on source but I wonder if there is a way to ensure the rule through standard Go testing?

Just to give an idea what I'm going to do:

Interface package:

```
package dal

type UserDal interface {
  GetUser(id int) User
}
```

Implementation package:

```
package dal_db_specific

import (
  "some_db"
  "dal"
)

type UserDalDbSpecific struct {
}

func (_ UserDalDbSpecific) GetUser(id int) User {
  some_db.executeQuery(...)
  ...
  return user
}

register_dal() {
  dal.UserDal = UserDalDbSpecific{}
}
```

User code package:

```
import (
  "dal"
  "some_db" <-- Fail here!
)

func someFunc() {
  user := dal.User.GetUser(1) // Right way
  some_db.DoSomething()  <-- Fail here!
}
```

Comment: If `dal` returns types different from those other `db` packages you can use reflection to check the `var`'s type, including package path. But if `dal` returns a type defined in `db`, instead of regexp you can use the `go/ast` and co. packages to determine how and where the `var` is being set in the source, but i'm not sure if it's fool proof... To be honest though, in case you want to hear someone's opinion,  it seems like you're overdoing it and having to do overly complicated testing is usually a smell of bad design.

Comment: The "dal" holds and interface var that is assigned by a respective DAL implementation. Think of dependency injection.

I'll add code to question.

Comment: Given your update, if you don't want to allow an import of a specific package and the use of that package, reflection isn't gonna help you, the `reflect` package is not able to tell you what packages were imported by the calling package, neither is it able to tell you how and where a specific package is used. I'd go with @David Joyner's solution.

Comment: What behavior are these tests trying to prevent? What is the cost of someone importing `some_db` directly? Do you not want people to accidentally connect to certain databases?  is this test solving the problem correctly?  Is it a safety thing?

Comment: @dm03514 There are 2 purpose of the tests. 1st is to ensure proper separation of concerns. 2nd to prevent compilation & tests speed degradation - for example importing something from "google.golang.org/appengine/datastore" can significantly increase compilation times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slightly more reliable than grep: parse the target source using the standard [`parser` package](https://golang.org/pkg/go/parser/) and inspect the AST. You'd be looking for [`ImportSpec`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/#ImportSpec) nodes matching the DB access packages. Fail the test if any are found.

Comment: I was thinking reflection should be faster if possible?

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok: reflection requires compiling and running the program, while parsing the file just relies on reading the source. You also can't reflect on a "package" -- if the package isn't used it doesn't exist in the compiled binary.

Comment: @Jimb but when I'm running standard Go unit tests it does compile package(s). And I assume reflection should work there just fine.

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok: reflection works on values. If you have a value you want to verify, you could check its type's PkgPath qualifier. You can't checks imports at runtime, because imports statements aren't executed code, they don't exist at runtime.

Comment: @JimB thanks, that is what I suspected. Seems the best option would be to go with parser AST option.